# Another "error reporting not working in PHP" post

Tags: php, wsod

All I get is a blank page. And, yes, I did read the dozens of similar questions asked.

I want this change to apply to all my scripts, so I went into `php.ini`. According to `phpinfo()`, it is located in `/etc`. So, I went there, and turned `error_reporting = E_ALL` and `error_display = On`. Still blank.

Its very frustrating, so I came here. What am I doing wrong? It is PHP5, Apache 2.2.17.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code?

Comment: Did you restart apache when you changed php.ini?

Comment: try using error_reporting(E_ALL) (eventually, E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE) in the first line of your php bootstrap file

Comment: Have you checked to make sure your page is getting parsed (right-click, view source)? Also, if the site is hosted, have you checked to make sure your host will let you change this setting?

Comment: In your `PHP` script was there any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did you restart apache when you changed php.ini? – Ryan 19 hours ago

That worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The ini-setting is called **display_errors** not **error_display**

Answer (score 1):

Additionally when using php and having multiple sites on the same host, you can copy the php.ini file into your sub sites and modify it specifically for those sites.

Many times it will not default to the root "public_html" php.ini file and you will need to copy this file in.